# COM call working on XP crashes Win7 application

Tags: windows-7, com, activex, freepascal

Sorry about kind of vague information about the background of this question, first the actual type library I am working with is subject to a non disclosure agreement, second I do not have direct access to the system where the problem is happening.

I have something like the following TLB for the COM interface of a device I am talking to in Free Pascal:

```
Device = interface(IDispatch)
  // ...
  function GetSubsystem: Subsystem; safecall;
  property Subsystem: Subsystem read GetSubsystem;
  // ...
end;

Subsystem = interface(IDispatch)
  // ...
  function GetSensors: Sensors; safecall;
  property Sensors: Sensors read GetSensors;
  // ...
end;

Sensors = interface(IDispatch)
  // ...
  function GetListItem(index: OleVariant): Sensor; safecall;
  property ListItem[index: OleVariant]: Sensor read GetListItem; default;
  // ...
end;

Sensor = interface(IDispatch)
  // ...
  function GetValue: Double; safecall;
  property Value: Double read GetValue;
  // ...
end;
```

If I read (according to the manufacturer's manual) a value from one of the sensors on Windows XP 32bit as follows

```
d := MyDevice.Subsystem.Sensors['ID23'].Value;
```

this works fine.

On Windows 7 64 bit, the manufacturer still has a 32bit COM interface, and all other calls from my 32bit exectuable work fine - just the one above makes my executable crash. It does not even raise an exception, it simply crashes. The same happens with

```
var o: oleVariant;
// ...
o = 'ID23';
d := MyDevice.Subsystem.Sensors[o].Value;
```

As I do not have access to said system directly, debugging is quite tedious and it took me a while to isolate the problem to exactly this call.

The interesting thing is that other programming languages using this same COM interface on Win7 64bit **do not** show this problem.

Does anyone have advice on how to approach this issue under the given circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you some pointers to try/be wary of:

- FPC 3.0 supports SEH exceptions for 64-bit, but not for 32-bit
- FPC seems to have some problem with default properties of dispatch interfaces. Try to use getlistitem() directly.